# Expected Iterable, but did not find one for field \"Noticia.categorias\"." Apollo Server

Tags: apollo

Buenas tengo el siguiente error en Apollo Server:

> Expected Iterable, but did not find one for field "Noticia.categorias"."

adjunto el código de typeDefs y resolvers

typeDefs.js

```
const { gql } = require('graphql-tag');

const typeDefs = gql`
    type Query{
        getNoticias: [Noticia!]!
    }
    type Noticia{
        id:Int
        titulo:String!
        contenido:String!
        categorias:[Categoria!]!
    }
    type Categoria{
        nombre:String!
        descripcion:String!
    }

`
module.exports = typeDefs
```

resolvers.js

```
const noticiones = [{
    id:1,
    titulo:'titulo para rellenar 1',
    contenido:'lorem ipsum 1',
    categorias:{    
        nombre:'deportes',
        descripcion:'Toda las noticias de los diferentes deportes',
    }
},{
    id:2,
    titulo:'titulo para rellenar 2',
    contenido:'lorem ipsum 2',
    categorias:{
        nombre:'politica',
        descripcion:'Todas las noticias relacionadas a la politica en general no solo de gobierno, sino de sociedad, cultura,etc',
    }
}]

const resolvers = {
    Query:{
        getNoticias:()=>noticiones,
    }
}

module.exports = resolvers
```

si en Apollo explorer hago la siguiente consulta

```
{
   getNoticias{
    titulo
    contenido
 }
}
```

obtengo:

```
{
  "data": {
    "getNoticias": [
      {
        "titulo": "titulo para rellenar 1",
        "contenido": "lorem ipsum 1"
      },
      {
        "titulo": "titulo para rellenar 2",
        "contenido": "lorem ipsum 2"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

osea obtengo el resultado esperado de la consulta, que es obtener titulo y contenido, pero como se ve en typeDefs el objeto **Noticia** contiene otro objeto **Categoría**, la cuestión es que antes si yo consultaba por el contenido de **categoría** dentro de **noticia** me arrojaba ya sea nombre o descripción o ambas según consulte. simplemente pare la ejecución del server por error
no toque nada del código (al menos eso creo)y cuando lo volví a levantar al server me daba ese error

> message": "Expected Iterable, but did not find one for field "Noticia.categorias".",

por si las dudas adjunto imagen del error
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

como digo antes funcionaba cuando hacia la consulta

```
{
  getNoticias {
    titulo
    contenido
    categorias {
      nombre
      descripcion
    }  
  }
}
```

la respuesta de la consulta arrojaba todo el objeto noticias incluyendo el contenido de categorías. Alguien sabe cual es el error, desde ya muchas gracias.

Comment: Haz definido el campo `categorias` como un Array: `categorias:[Categoria!]!`, pero luego, al crearlo, lo haces como un objeto: `categorias: { nombre:'deportes', ... }`. Debes usar Array: `categorias: [ { nombre:'deportes', ... } ]`. Prueba eso y comenta el resultado.

Comment: @MauricioContreras, no entendi bien lo que me queres decir, lo solucione quitando el corchete al objeto categoria de noticias osea quedaria noticia{categorias: categoria!} nose si te referias a eso, gracias por tu tiempo